# Get author ID of a post in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, foreach

Im creating a loop where it pulls info about a users activity. the code is on the author page and what i want to to is get the current author ID, so based on what author page the user is on it will fetch the ID of that author.

See below, i would want AUTHOR-ID to be the ID of the current author.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                            var pieData = [
                            <?php

                            $user_id = AUTHOR-ID;

                            /* Get all categories */
                            $rand = array('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f');


                            $categories = get_terms( 'category', 'orderby=count&hide_empty=0' );

                            /* Loop for each category to count the posts of the user */
                            foreach($categories as $category)
                            {
                            $color = '#'.$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)];
                               $cat_name = $category->name;
                               $cat_id = $category->term_id;
                               $post_count = count(get_posts("cat=$cat_id&post_author=$user_id"));

                               echo "

                                            {
                                                value: ".$post_count.",
                                                color:'".$color."',
                                                label: ".$user_id."
                                            },";

                            }
                            ?>
                            ]
                            var myPie = new Chart(document.getElementById("piec").getContext("2d")).Pie(pieData);
                        </script>
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try with this :

```
<?php $author_id=$post->post_author; ?>
```

it will give you current author id.

or this one will helps you more:

```
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();                      

$args = array(
    'author'        =>  $current_user->ID, // I could also use $user_ID, right?        
    );

// get his posts 'ASC'
$current_user_posts = get_posts( $args );
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

You can use [`the_author_meta`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_author_meta/) to print out the author's meta details, such as their ID:

`the_author_meta('ID');`

You can also use [`get_the_author_meta`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_author_meta/) to store this value in a variable:

`$author_id = get_the_author_meta('ID');`

Answer (score 3):

On an author archive the following will get the author ID:

```
$author_ID = get_query_var('author');
```

This will get you a lot more information:

```
$pageobj = get_queried_object();
```

## Reference:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object

Answer (score 1):

maybe the following link be useful:
https://www.intelliwolf.com/get-author-id-from-post-id/

```
$author_id = get_post_field( 'post_author', $post_id );
```

you can also use below fields:

```
get_post_field( 'Your_Field', $post_id )
```

- post_author
- post_content
- post_title
- post_excerpt
- post_status
- post_type
- etc

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
global $wp_query;
$thePostID = $wp_query->post->ID;
$postdata = get_postdata($thePostID);
$authorID = $postdata['Author ID'];
```

or something like this

```
<?php $author_id=$post->post_author; ?>
<img src="<?php echo the_author_meta( 'avatar' , $author_id ); ?> " width="140" height="140" class="avatar" alt="<?php echo the_author_meta( 'display_name' , $author_id ); ?>" />
<?php echo the_author_meta( 'user_nicename' , $author_id ); ?>
```

Comment: Author ID should be Author_ID

Answer (score -2):

Working code here

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                            var pieData = [
                            <?php
                                $user_id = get_query_var('author');

                                $rand = array('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f');

                                //get all posts from author
                                $args = array(
                                    'post_type' => 'post',
                                    'author'=> $queried_object->ID
                                );

                                $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

                                if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :

                                    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

                                        //put categories in array
                                        $cat = get_the_category( get_the_ID() );
                                        $terms[] = $cat[0]->term_id;

                                    endwhile;

                                    wp_reset_query();
                                endif;

                                //count matching categories (array vals)
                                $countVal = array_count_values($terms);
                                foreach($countVal as $count){

                                    $color = '#'.$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)];

                                    echo "  {
                                            value: ".$count.",
                                            color:'".$color."'
                                            },";
                                }

                            ?>
                            ]
                            var myPie = new Chart(document.getElementById("piec").getContext("2d")).Pie(pieData);
                        </script>
```