# Show authors only own courses in dropdown

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I am using Buddypress groups and part of the Group set up is to associate it to a Post (it's a custom post type called 'course').

The problem is that when associating a group to a particular post, the dropdown shows Authors all sitewide posts, (i.e. including from other authors). I want it so they can only see, and select from, their own posts - i.e. associate their group to one of their posts.

The code that is behind the current dropdown (which shows all authors' posts) is:

```
<select name="bp_group_course" id="bp-group-course">
    <option value="-1"><?php _e( '--Select--', 'buddypress-learndash' ); ?></option>
    <?php
    foreach ( $courses as $course ) {
        $group_attached = get_post_meta( $course->ID, 'bp_course_group', true );
        if ( !empty( $group_attached ) && ( '-1' != $group_attached ) && $course->ID != $group_status ) {
            continue;
        }
        ?><option value="<?php echo $course->ID; ?>" <?php echo (( $course->ID == $group_status )) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>><?php echo $course->post_title; ?></option><?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

$courses seems to come from:

```
 if ( ! empty( $course_id ) ) {
            $courses = array( get_post( $course_id ) );
        } elseif ( ! empty( $group_id ) ){
            $courses = learndash_group_enrolled_courses( $group_id );
            $courses = array_map( 'intval', $courses );
            $courses = ld_course_list( array( 'post__in' => $courses, 'array' => true ) );
        } else {
            $courses = ld_course_list( array( 'array' => true ) );
        }
```

How can I limit it to just the currently logged in user's posts?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Where does `$courses` come from?

Comment: I belive this is setting it -  if ( ! empty( $course_id ) ) {
    $courses = array( get_post( $course_id ) );
   } elseif ( ! empty( $group_id ) ){
    $courses = learndash_group_enrolled_courses( $group_id );
    $courses = array_map( 'intval', $courses );
    $courses = ld_course_list( array( 'post__in' => $courses, 'array' => true ) );
   } else {
    $courses = ld_course_list( array( 'array' => true ) );
   }

Comment: Edit your question please.

Comment: Hi Mike, I have edited the question. Apologies

Comment: I would loop through `$courses` and check if the [post author](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176691/get-author-id-of-a-post-in-wordpress) matches the [current user id](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_user_id/), and if not, remove it.

Comment: I'm really not familiar enough with wordpress development for that to mean too much to me. Am I right in thinking I need to write a snippet that changes $courses? So that this means that '$course->ID;' in the option value loop is only those courses of the current post author? (Really sorry, I am a bit of a newbie.)

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. I am also not overly familiar with Wordpress which is why I posted that as a comment trying to lead you in the right direction instead of writing a full answer.